# Formula inside of Formula range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking for a way to have a dynamically changing range inside a formula.
For example I am currently using this formula to sum the digits before a space of the cell range:

```
="Used: "&SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(D2:D2,FIND(" ",D2:D2,1)-1)))
```

I am looking to replace the **D2:D2** with something more like **D2:D(COUNTIF(D2:D100,"*")+1)**
which will essentially change the range to include the cells with new information. So if I add 3 more rows of numbers it will now sum **D2:D5**.

That formula posted doesn't work and I am not sure if it's possible to do something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use non Volatile INDEX:

```
="Used: "&SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(D2:INDEX(D:D,MATCH("zzz",D:D)),FIND(" ",D2:INDEX(D:D,MATCH("zzz",D:D)),1)-1)))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Works great! Thank you!